# Sizing GUI for different devices

Tags: user-interface, google-apps-script

I am creating a small app which I would like to function nicely on multiple devices. Utilising Google-app-script I have got the functionality down however I can't seem to get the GUI to re size depending on the device that is viewing it.

Below is an example of how I am currently setting the height and width of the window which works however it is a fixed value and I can't seem to find a simple way to get the screen height and width?

```
   var app = UiApp.createApplication();
   app.setHeight(600).setWidth(400)
```

Comment: If you were using HTML Service, you could control and dynamically change size formatting with CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height can be set as a percentage:

[setHeight()  Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/scroll-panel#setHeight(String))

If you set the value to 100%, it simply uses 100% of whatever screen it's on.

Comment: no idea how I over looked this simple fix... But thank you ever so much